# Pass url as a parameter in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm passing parameter to a url which is also a url, parameter is : `profile/foldername/imgname.jpg` when i pass `profile/foldername/imgname.jpg` as a parameter then i only get `imgname.jpg` in my laravel controller but i want to pass whole url as a parameter.

> I'm using following code to pass image path to a url:

```
removeImage: function(index,img_path) {
      var img_path = encodeURIComponent(img_path);
      axios.get(`/api/backend/delete-gallery/${img_path}`, { headers: this.header() }).then((response) => {
```

In network tab getting this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/backend/delete-gallery/post%2FUTS7C210103124422%2F1256160041.png
```

> route:

```
Route::get('delete-gallery/{path}', 'API\Controller@deleteGallery');
```

getting it in controller :

```
dd($request->path);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The [axios GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) has an example on how to pass parameters

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to handle this, I'll mention two of them in the following:

- **Encode URI**

```
HTTP://img.com/img.com --> http%3A%2F%2Fimg.com%2Fimg.jpg
```

And send it to the backend service, then you need to decode the string in the PHP by using [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function.

```
let img_path = encodeURIComponent("HTTP://img.com/img.jpg")
```

- **Base64**

You can also use [btoa()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp) to encode the URL and then send it to the backend. the only thing you need  to do is decoding the URL to the origin one by using
[base64_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) in the PHP side.

Comment: :using ` let img_path = encodeURI(img_path);` but it does not get encoded.

Comment: share that fragment of code here, you may have some small mistakes in the code.

Comment: take a screenshot from network inspector tools on chrome, to see if the Request URL  that you are sending is correct or not.

Comment: I think it's better to use base64 approach to see if it's working or your code is getting impacted by something else.